# html-css auto slider buttons not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

Try to make slider, every thing working good, Except the button hover when change the slide not changing with the slid.

[this is link for the photo number 3 but the hover color on the button number 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAqrC.png)

You can run the code snippet and check it.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
     dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-white", "");
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " w3-white";
}
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";
       
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(carousel, 2500); // Change image every 2 seconds
    
}
```

```css
.mySlides {display:none}
.w3-left, .w3-right, .w3-badge {cursor:pointer}
.w3-badge {height:13px;width:13px;padding:0}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<body>

<div class="w3-content w3-display-container" style="max-width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="w3-center w3-container w3-section w3-large w3-text-white w3-display-bottommiddle" style="width:100%">
    <div class="w3-left w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</div>
    <div class="w3-right w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</div>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(1)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(2)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(3)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(4)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(5)"></span>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

so any help to solve this problem, Please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to put in the "carousel" function the code that highlights the right dot:

```js
// I moved these here because if the number of images is always the same,
// why search for these elements every time?
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");

var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
     dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-white", "");
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " w3-white";
}
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";
       
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
       dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-white", "");
    }
    dots[myIndex-1].className += " w3-white";
    setTimeout(carousel, 2500); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

```css
.mySlides {display:none}
.w3-left, .w3-right, .w3-badge {cursor:pointer}
.w3-badge {height:13px;width:13px;padding:0}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<body>

<div class="w3-content w3-display-container" style="max-width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="w3-center w3-container w3-section w3-large w3-text-white w3-display-bottommiddle" style="width:100%">
    <div class="w3-left w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</div>
    <div class="w3-right w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</div>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(1)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(2)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(3)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(4)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(5)"></span>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```